# Changing the http header info to hide server info

Tags: php, http, http-headers

My question is whether I can omit my server info from being sent in the http header using php? I know by itself it is not dangerous, but humor me. If I wanted to omit that information, how would I do this. How about if I wanted to insert false server information as to lead potential harmful users astray? I have looked at the php doc, but I could not find it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you not able to edit it on the server itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if using PHP to do this is the right approach. Is the server running Apache? If so, you can add the following options to your config file to hide server info:

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerSignature Off
```

To hide PHP info, edit your `php.ini` and add the line:

```
expose_php Off
```

Or, if this option already exists, change from `On` to `Off`.

Reference: http://www.debianadmin.com/apache-tipshide-apache-information-php-software-version.html

Comment: I see what you are saying. I was under the assumption that those settings only hid the version info when an error occurred. But I looked at the link, thank you very much for your timely response.

Comment: The `ServerToken` controls what is sent through headers. Using `ProductOnly` sends something like `Server: Apache`

Comment: And, the other option, `ServerSignature`, is used in error pages.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the output of even the minimal "Server: Apache"?

Comment: BTW, if you are using a recent version of Ubuntu (~12+), these directives have been moved to /etc/apache2/conf.d/security. You must edit that file for your changes to have an effect. (From pgschk on AskUbuntu: askubuntu.com/a/184366 and verified by me.)

Comment: @AdamFriedman the only way to remove the header is to recompile Apache from source (https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026). You can, however, change it to any arbitrary value using ModSecurity (http://superuser.com/a/286825/148758).