# Remove server info and PHP info from response header

Tags: apache, php-ini

How can i prevent `server info` and `php info` to be displayed in response header

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the http header info to hide server info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781878/changing-the-http-header-info-to-hide-server-info)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

for server info add the following lines in apache2.conf

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly

ServerSignature Off
```

For PHP info

in your php.ini

turn

```
expose_php = off
```

Comment: The latest syntax on debian & ubuntu servers is:
`ServerSignature Off`
`ServerTokens Prod`
For anyone using those distros.

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Ubuntu (~12+), these directives have been moved to /etc/apache2/conf.d/security. You must edit that file for your changes to have an effect (says pgschk on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/184366 and verified by me).

Comment: More recently, these  are in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf`.