# Completely remove "Apache" in HTTP headers?

Tags: apache, http, http-headers

I did the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130443/), and placed

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

in `apache2.conf`, but, it appears to only remove the version.

Basically, the header now shows `Apache` instead of `Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)`.

Is it possible to completely remove the word `Apache` in the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be not configurable based on the [latest](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens) doc.
Prod would be the most restrictive

```
ServerTokens Prod[uctOnly]
    Server sends (e.g.): Server: Apache
```