# Is it possible to reduce the http response header size for a REST api?

Tags: apache, http

I'm working on a REST api. Here is one of the response header

```
Date: Mon, 19 May 2014 08:31:04 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.10
Content-Length: 2207 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

It's 318 bytes long. That means for example my response body is 100 bytes, it's only about 25% of its total length. So I'm wondering if it's possible to reduce the response header size? (I know it could be useful for browser, but for my REST Client, I don't think it's so important.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the http header info to hide server info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781878/changing-the-http-header-info-to-hide-server-info). That aught to do it.

Comment: That helps me to reduce the header size from 318 bytes to 159 bytes. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the "Server" value and remove "X-Powered-By" header (using Ubuntu file locations):

- Set "ServerTokens Prod" in /etc/apache2/conf.d/security
- Set "expose_php = Off" in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

**Edit**: for small bodies, compression can add an overhead. To disable it, add to your .htacces or apache config, for example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/endpoint" no-gzip=1
```